# How can I replace class_createInstance in arc?

Tags: xcode4, ios5, automatic-ref-counting

I have this code and need to port it to arc but I dont know how:

```
        case FIELDTYPE_OBJECT:
            className = [fieldType substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(2, [fieldType length]-3)];
            rel =  class_createInstance(NSClassFromString(className), sizeof(unsigned));
            Class theClass = [rel class];

            if ([rel isKindOfClass:[DbObject class]]) {
                //Load the record...
                NSInteger Id = [rs intForColumn:[theClass relationName]];
                if (Id==0) {
                    fieldValue = [rel init];
                } else {                    
                    Db *db = [Db currentDb];

                    fieldValue = [db loadById: theClass theId:Id];
                }
            }
            break;
```

The error is:

```
error: 'class_createInstance' is unavailable: not available in automatic reference counting mode
```

How replace it?

I need to build class objects in runtime.

Answer (score 3):

The most straightforward solution is to add another file which has -fno-objc-arc set on it, and which has a function which calls class_createInstance() as above.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#include <objc/objc-runtime.h>
id object = [[NSClassFromString(@"TheClassName") alloc] init];
```

Comment: That won't handle the extraBytes parameter to class_createInstance

Comment: Is this still required when using alloc init ?

Comment: Ah yes, indeed. Extra bytes is, well, extra bytes in addition to what's normally alloc'd. . . Just voted on Rob Rix's solution.

Answer (score 1):

Create a separated `.h`/**`.c`** files and put something like this.

```
id const
MyCreateInstanceOfClass(Class const class)
{
    id      instance    =   class_createInstance(class, 0);
    return  instance;
}
```

`#include` the `.h`, and call it. No need to put `-fno-bjc-arc` switch for each file.